# How to calculate this sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

[image]

$$\sum^{n-m}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!\times (n-k+1)!} = $$

How to simplify this to a one-term form. I have trouble with it. Thank you for reading and trying.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that what you are asking for is possible?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Optimism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{k!(n-k+1)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{(n-k+1)+(k)}{k!(n-k+1)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{1}{(k-1)!(n-(k-1))!})$$ so
$$\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k+1)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}-\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!(n-(k-1))!})$$
Now use telescope rule.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k+1)!}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac{(-1)^k}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!}\\
&=\frac 1{(n+1)!}\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}(-1)^k\binom {n+1}k}\\
&=\frac 1{(n+1)!}\color{blue}{(-1)^{n-m}\binom n{n-m}}\qquad\qquad \text{(*)}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{(n+1)!}\binom nm\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

*refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217459/bonferroni-inequalities/1219873#1219873).

Comment: Wow, this is a good solution too! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks!